# What does the perpendicular symbol mean when it is a superscript?

Tags: matrices, cryptography, coding-theory

This has to do with error-correcting codes.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpXg9.png

Sorry for the link; I don't have enough reputation to post images.

Comment: It's almost certainly defined somewhere earlier in the same book. Have you looked?

Comment: In coding theory (and in all linear algebra actually) it means the dual code. If $C$ is a subspace of a vector space $V$ equipped with a bilinear form $(\ ,\ )$ (not necessarily an inner product but something like it) then
$$C^\perp=\{x\in V\mid (x,c)=0\ \forall c\in C\}.$$

Comment: If you are aware of dual codes then the question is asking you to prove that the parity-check code are the dual of repetition code.

Comment: Perfect thank you! It is about dual codes; we just hadn't used that notation in class yet.

Comment: It’s just as well that you don’t have enough reputation to post images yet, especially one of two sentences that are crucial to understanding what it is you’re asking about. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to people using screen readers. Please take the time to learn how to format mathematical expressions with MathJax. You can find a tutorial and quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?s=5|34.8361).

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha, it represents the rotation of the two dimensional vector, in this case C, 90° counterclockwise.  So if C=<Cx,Cy>, C-perp=<-Cy,Cx>.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PerpendicularVector.html        This convention is used surprisingly rarely despite being incredibly useful.  If this isn’t what you were looking for, I apologize.